# How to fix "Not all control paths return a value" warning in c++?

Tags: c++

[This isn't homework, I'm working through Bjarne Stroustrup's book Programming Principles and Practice Using C++ on my own]

I'm trying to make a simple program using a vector to convert a digit from 1 to 9 into its string equivalent, and vice-versa, using the same input loop, and my program seems to roughly work, but I get a warning "Not all control paths return a value". How can I fix this, and account for unexpected input?

Also, the `while (true)` condition seems messy. How can I adapt my code to give the user an option to manually exit the `while` loop?

```
#include "..\std_lib_facilities_revised.h"

vector<string> num_words = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };

string print_num()
{
    int i = num_words.size();
    string s = " ";
    if (cin >> i) {
        if (i > -1 && i < num_words.size()) {
            return num_words[i];
        }
    }
    cin.clear();
    if (cin >> s) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num_words.size(); ++j) {
            if (s == num_words[j]) {
                return to_string(j);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    while (true) {
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cout << print_num() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Make all the return paths return a value. In `string print_num()`  you promised to return a string.

Comment: The `print_num` function can skip all conditions and go straight to the end of the function (e.g., if i == 0 and s == ""). In this case, you still need to return something. This warning should not be ignored nor hidden.

Comment: Also, if you ignore the warning and your function goes to the end without returning a `std::string`, the behavior of your program now becomes undefined.

Comment: @DanielBarker I've reverted your edits to your post because they completely changed the meaning of your question and invalidated the existing answers. This would prevent future users with a similar problem from finding this Q/A. I encourage you to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), assuming you've searched for an existing answer to your problem.

Comment: @alterigel Okay, I'll do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to return some value at the end of the function in case all the if conditions (`if (s == num_words[j])`, `if (i > -1 && i < num_words.size())`) aren't met.

```
string print_num()
{
    int i = num_words.size();
    string s = " ";
    if (cin >> i) {
        if (i > -1 && i < num_words.size()) {
            return num_words[i];
        }
    }
    cin.clear();
    if (cin >> s) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num_words.size(); ++j) {
            if (s == num_words[j]) {
                return to_string(j);
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! How can I deal with when a user enters an int which is too large, such as 10? My program gets stuck there. I'll edit my original question to show this.

Comment: @DanielBarker _"How can I deal with when a user enters an int which is too large, such as 10?"_ Throw an exception maybe?

Comment: @DanielBarker when you enter a value that is not within 0-9, the if condition `if (i > -1 && i < num_words.size())` won't satisfy and thus it won't return the number string immediately and will prompt for the input of variable `s` (`cin >> s`) so you just need to enter any string value for `s` in order to finish the input prompt.

Answer (score 0):

If both `cin >> s` return `false`, neither of the `return` statements will be hit.

Answer (score -2):

```
string print_num()
{
    int i = num_words.size();
    string s = " ";
    string error = "Enter valid input.";
if (cin >> i) {
    if (i > -1 && i < num_words.size()) {
        return num_words[i];
    }
}
cin.clear();
if (cin >> s) {
    for (int j = 0; j < num_words.size(); ++j) {
        if (s == num_words[j]) {
            return to_string(j);
        }
    }
}
// NO RETURN HERE
}

int main()
{
    while (true) {
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cout << print_num() << '\n';
        }
    }
```

Comment: No `return` in main() isn't a problem. It's the only function that the language will provide an implicit `return 0;` for you.

Comment: @user3344003 Code only answer without explanation, seriously?